# Adding 2 dropdown lists together

Tags: jquery

I need some help with this, I have 2 drop down lists (1 for book quantity selection and one for add slides selection (yes or no)
Both drop downs work perfectly and gives a price when selected

My question is, how do i add the 1st divprice with the second one to give a Total ?

Books Selection with cost

```js
function changeddl($this){
  $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("Price: R " + $this.value):"");
};
function changedd2($this){
  $("#divprice2").text($this.value>0?("Price: R " + $this.value):"");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Books" onchange="changeddl(this)" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
  <option>Select Number of Copies</option>
  <option value="358.00">1 Copy</option>
  <option value="716.00">2 Copies</option>
  <option value="1074.00">3 Copies</option>
</select>

<div id="divprice" </div>


<!-- Slide Selection Yes or No - with cost -->

<div class="clear"> </div>
</li> 
<li>
  <select name="Select2"onchange="changedd2 (this)" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">

    <option>Add Slides</option>
    <option value="0"> No</option>
    <option value="716.00"> Yes</option>

  </select>

  <div id="divprice2" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #006699; font-size: x-large"></div>
```

Comment: can u make jsfiddle..so i can figure out..

Comment: you have to just get selected option's value from both `select` in onchange ()...get value like`$('#selectorId option:selected').val()` from both and add it

Comment: Debin Thank you for the quick reply, i'm new to all of this, I've got no idea what im doing lol. could you perhaps help me with this (the code was copied from internet)

Comment: yah sure..basically u have to add selected item..right? if yes then m making code for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('#totalprice')[0].innerHTML = parseInt($('#copy option:selected').val(), 10) +
      parseInt($('#addSlide option:selected').val(), 10)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="copy">
  <option value="1">1 copy</option>
  <option value="2">2 copy</option>
  <option value="3">3 copy</option>
</select>

<select id="addSlide">
  <option value="0"> No</option>
  <option value="716.00"> Yes</option>
</select>

<div id="totalprice">
  dfsfs
</div>
```

This may help you..if your requirement is different then let me know :)

Comment: Thx Debin,
Works exactly the way its suppose to!

Comment: Sorry Debin, Need to ask you another question.
The Currency Value is missing now, The code you gave me adds perfectly and works like a dream.
But the currency (R) (rand) Doesn't display in front of Totalprice, only the total it added from the 2 dropdown lists.
Any way we can fix this by adding an R in front of the total when its displayed?

Comment: sorry for late reply..is it solved now or not?letme know if no @NealFourie

Comment: Happy new year :) @NealFourie

Answer (score 0):

change your function changedd2 like this

```
function changedd2($this){
    var total = parseInt($this.value, 10)  + parseInt($('#Books').val(), 10)
    $("#divprice2").text($this.value>0?("Price: R " + total):"");
};
```

Comment: Great! thanx Manu S, it works. Only one question is there a way to refresh the Slides Total. 
When the books (copies) is selected and Yes to slides are selected.. it works perfect, but when you change the copy of the books, after you have selected Yes to the slides - total amount stays the same (only by disabling the add slides and Selecting yes again) it refreshes the total. Any way to work around this?